# Android app not Launching in Com.onesignal Notification click

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I am using com.onesignal mobile push notification in my android app . I have used Notificationhandler to start an activity on notification click .It is working when the app running on background but if I clear my memory and the send a notification in my phone . Nothing happens... please help me with this problem

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notification does not receive by some android mobiles if the app is force closed or cleared by the recent activity. You can check the `Onesignal` doc which mentions it properly.

> When an app is in a "Force Stopped" state most events including GCM/FCM messages for push notifications will not be received.

Check this info: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown

Comment: I am always getting the notification.But I want to start an specific activity on notification click .that is not happening when app is not running in the background.what is the solution for this?